# Comparing datasets from 2 biological replicates

Tags: r, regression, correlation, data-visualization, microarray

I have two datasets containing experiment data based on two biological replicates. I wonder what the best statistical methods are to find out and test how similar these two datasets are, and also how do I sensibly graphically show the results since each of the the datasets contain thousands of rows. I will like to do this analysis in R.
Thanks

Edit:

Data sample:

```
        Rep1    Rep2
Row1    1.0426  1.1337
Row2    -2.21   -2.1997
Row3    0.5002  0.6933
Row4    -4.2332 -3.9332
Row5    0.9000  0.8700
```

Comment: It will be useful if you can post here a sample of your data set, eg first 5 rows. If you work in R you can post output of command "head(mydata)" .

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? In what sense do you want that tested?

Comment: I actually want to know how close (or how far) the data points are when the  biological replicates are compared. I want to be able to either accept or reject the biological replicates.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to graphic display advised by Hotaka, following test can also be run:

1. Pearson's correlation: to see the degree of correlation
2. Difference of each pair of values can be calculated. The descriptive statistics of the differences will be informative regarding the mean and SD of difference, the range, the maximum and mean difference.
3. If there is some order in which the rows have been listed, a plot of row number on x-axis and difference on y-axis will show in which area the difference in more.

If you post in you question what exactly do the numbers mean, one may be able to suggest better methods, for example, possible role of residual plots from regression analysis. In addition, many packages are available for genetic analysis which may be useful here.

Edit: If you are using R and your data.frame is mydf, then these command will give you the differences and their summary:

```
mydf$diffs = with(mydf, Rep2-Rep1)
summary(mydf$diffs)
```

You may consider viewing the differences in raw values rather than these log values. You can plot these differences and their density in order of rows by following simple commands

```
plot(mydf$diffs)
plot(density(mydf$diffs))
```

For more questions regarding R commands you should post at http://stackoverflow.com

There are many genetics package listed on http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Genetics.html . Bioconductor (http://www.bioconductor.org/) may be especially useful.

Comment: Nice suggestions! The data are from gene expression studies. But how can I easily accomplish steps 2 and 3. There is a constraint in that the data has thousands of rows. Please name the genetic analysis packages.

Comment: AFAIK, usual gene expression data is generally not negative and has 0 as the lower limit. Can you provide a link to the kind of gene expression studies this data is from or explain it in a bit more detail? Because there are different kinds of packages for analysis of genetic data.

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to add that they are log2 data.

Comment: Please see the edit in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by plotting those 2 variables on a scatterplot, and also plot a y=x line. If your data is a dataframe object called DATA, you can run

```
plot(DATA$Rep1~DATA$Rep2)
abline(0,1)
```

If the dots line up in a line very close to each other, the two variables are highly correlated. If those dots are close to the y=x line, then the numerical values are close to each other.

From the first 5 rows of your data, I suspect the correlation is high and positive, and they will fall very close to the line.